# HttpDateParser problem

Tags: blackberry, sdk

I having a problem when convert String to Date in Blackberry SDK. Please support for me.
This is my code:

```
String date = "Mon May 09 09:00:00 GMT 2011";
Date formatter = new Date();
formatter.setTime(HttpDateParser.parse(date));
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formatStr);
string dateString = dateFormat.format(formatter);
```

purpsoe of the function is format date MMM dd, YYYY.
But after i run the function, it will return result that I unexpected.

Expected: May 09, 2011
UnExpected : Jan,01,1970.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `"Mon May 09 09:00:00 GMT 2011"` is not a supported by `HttpDateParser` date format. Since the `HttpDateParser.parse()` does not throw an exception, I guess it simply return 0 in case of an unsupported format.

Comment: Can you please give me a suggested in the case?

Comment: For instance "Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT". Please see the API.